# Как установить sudo в debian

Tags: debian, sudo

Пытаюсь установить **sudo** из терминала под пользователем root командой

```
apt-get install sudo
```

Выдается ошибка:

> E: Не удалось получить доступ к файлу блокировки /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Ресурс временно недоступен)
>
> E: Не удалось выполнить блокировку управляющего каталога (/var/lib/dpkg/); он уже используется другим процессом?

Как еще можно установить **sudo**?

Comment: Вы проверяли, что у вас никаких других apt-get не запущено?

Comment: Да, проблема в этом, был запущен менеджер пакетов на другом экране. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в том, что уже был запущен менеджер пакетов на другом экране.